# 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' but file is still being copied

Tags: c#

I have code that I am trying to use to backup the host file. When I run the code, I get the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The weird thing is that the file is being copied.  I am not sure what the code is referring to because if the exception itself wasn't being thrown, everything would be in order (or so it would seem).

The code is as follows:

```
private void BackUpHost()
        {
            string fileName = "hosts";
            string newFileName = "hosts.bak";
            string sourcePath = @"c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc";
            string targetPath = @"c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc";

            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, newFileName);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);
                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, newFileName);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which one of the two `System.IO.File.Copy` commands are giving the exception? Is your application running with Admin privileges?

Comment: The following line is throwing the exception: `System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true);` and I am running the program in debug mode.  Should I compile it differently, or is there something I can/should do in debug mode?

Comment: Look closely at what you are doing with `destFile` up to that line. (Hint: there is no filename in sourcePath). Put a Breakpoint at the start of your method and verify all the variables are set as you expect them to be

Comment: @BerndLinde: As far as I can tell, the Host file is just a "file."  It has to extension, which means I am not sure how to refer to it as a file rather than as a directory.

Comment: `sourcePath` does not have a filename (aka "hosts") in it

Comment: @BerndLinde, but it must because the "hosts" file is properly copied.  It just also throws an exception

Comment: I have a hosts.bak file in that directory. If I change `string fileName = "hosts";` to `string fileName = "hosts.bak";` and `string newFileName = "hosts.bak";` to `string newFileName = "hosts.bak2";` I get the same error, despite the file .bak file being legitimately backed up, and despite all paths leading unambiguously to filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain what I meant in my comments, let us "step" through your code and show why you are getting the exception. The below is the same process as putting a breakpoint into your code and using <kbd>F10</kbd> to step over each breakpoint and looking at the "Local Variables" section of the debugger windows.

```
private void BackUpHost()
{
  string fileName = "hosts";
  string newFileName = "hosts.bak";
  string sourcePath = @"c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc";
  string targetPath = @"c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc";

  string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
  // sourceFile = "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
  string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, newFileName);
  // destFile = "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.bak"

  if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
  {
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
  }

  System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true); // First File.Copy() call
  // File "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.bak" is created as a 
  // copy of "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" if either UAC is
  // disabled or the application is run as Administrator.
  // Otherwise "UnauthorizedAccessException - Access to path denied" is thrown

  if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
  {
    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourcePath); // Setting of fileName is not used in your code again, is this intended or a mistake?
    // fileName = "etc" (Since the value of sourcePath is "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc", GetFileName() sees the "etc" part as the FileName.
    // Should this not have been GetFileName(sourceFile) ??
    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, newFileName);
    // destFile = "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.bak"
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true); // Second File.Copy() call
    // This is where your exception happens since you are trying to copy
    // the file "etc" (which is actually a folder)
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
  }
}
```

The reason why you see a "hosts.bak" file is because of the first `File.Copy()` call that you do. Since the file is being created, I must assume that you have UAC disabled on your environment or your Visual Studio is being always run as Administrator.

More information about debugging and stepping into/over code can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  This was way more than I expected.  There was actually a compounding of mistakes here; I hadn't realized that first line of code that copied the file was there, which made me totally misunderstand what was happening. (I removed a lot of unnecessary code from what I shared, so it was easier for you to read.  It should have been easier for me to read too)

This perfectly solves my problem.  Thanks so much!